# Django, How to clear the previous data model thoroughly?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm viewing my admin site, but in the Add Groups page, I can still see the available permissions that I have deleted before. and in my models.py I haven't configured any of these table yet.

[image: These are the table I have already deleted]

Does this mean I didn't clear my database thoroughly? Is there any way to delete all of these, just leave the permissions I have in this list?

Thank you!

---

Update:

I dropped my database created a new one, and re-built my data model. I can't view my previous group now :)

Answer (score 0):

I dropped my database and my previous database user (Don't know if a new user is necessary), and created a new one. Then all my previous groups in this list disappeared. :)